# If the closure of a subset $X\subset C$ of the continuum satisfies $\overline{X}=C$, then all elements of $X$ are limit points of $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Here a question that I come up with when doing the backward direction of the following problem:

A subset $X\subset C$ is dense in $C$ if, and only if, $\overline{X}=C.$

To prove that $X$ is dense, we have to show that every point in the continuum is a limit point of $X$. Thus given $\overline{X}=C$, it suffices to prove that all elements of $X$ are limit points of $C$. How to prove the fact that $\overline{X}=C \implies \text{all elements of } X \text{ are limit points}$.

Thanks!

Comment: It's the other way around. If $X \subset C$ is dense in $C$, then every point of $C$ is a limit point of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

If $y\in X$ and $y$ is not a limit point of $X$ then there is an open $U$ of the space $C$ such that  $U\cap X=\{y\}.$ But $U\ne \{y\},$ so there exists $z\in U$ with $z\ne y.$ And $z\not \in X$ (because $z\ne y\in U$ and the only member of $U\cap X$ is $y$).

There is an open $V$ in the space $C$ with $z\in V$ and $y\not \in V.$  But then $U\cap V$ is an open set containing $z$ and disjoint from $X,$  contradicting $\bar X=C.$